# Best way without an internet lookup to secure a paid for application

Tags: c#, .net, security

I have an application that I am currently selling that I want to expand.

However I don't want people to just be able to copy the EXE and give to their friends etc. I know its an almost impossible task but I want to make it as hard as possible for the non techies.

Obviously I could do a key lookup over the internet to a database every time they start the app but that would mean:

1. Lots of internet traffic to my server which I would pay for.
2. People without internet access (or my server being down / or a router somewhere) could prevent the app from working if the key couldn't be verified.
3. Clever people with Wireshark / traffic sniffers could decode whatever key I am sending back to activate the app and then write something to bypass it.

Therefore I was thinking of something simple such as a checksum that would be related to the computers name / MAC address / IP (at the time of purchase) and then store it in the computers registry (1 licence = 1 key).

Then when the app opened it would check for the right registry key and compare it to a setting variable inside the app to ensure it matches before the app starts up.

If someone gave the app to another computer the key wouldn't exist (if they had purchased it I could give them a special once over-ride key which would re-set their key in the registry etc). Someone without the original payment details couldn't get this.

Does anyone have any better ideas that doesn't revolve around internet lookups etc or see any problems with the idea I am proposing?

The app is written in C# as a windows forms application in .NET 4.5

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can prevent #3 using assymetric crypto.

Comment: However, you cannot prevent attackers from modifying the EXE and removing your code.

Comment: There are quite a few commercial licensing applications designed to do this for you.  You're probably better off using one of those rather than trying to roll your own.  It'll be cheaper in the end to get something non-trivial to break.  (Note that with no internet access it's provably *impossible* to get a system that's unbreakable, you can only make it hard.)

Comment: Yes which I why I know without being able to 100% guarantee having a server up 100% of the time to check keys (encrypted etc) that I would be stuck. I didn't realise reverse engineering EXE programs were that good now - last time I looked I only found apps that got basic form elements back not class code etc. This is why I thought a simple hashed key from MAC ADDR/IP/COMP NAME in reg & checks for it would be easy and stop majority of people from hacking it. I know I won't be able to stop everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, in that case i would recommend doing something with the Product ID - that way the ID can be checked on start-up of the program. But, do remember that the 'allowed key' will have to be entered into some database either online or behind the application itself.

Then, when the program is started it will check the users product ID and check it against the ID which has been put on the 'allow list'.

And it depends how the 'allowed ID' is stored. If your just storing the singular ID for a user in the code and then compiling it - no. If you have a huge list of allowed ID's in some sort of database separate from the application - yes. And it depends on the skill level of a hacker, most of the good hackers will be able to accomplish what they set out to achieve - no matter how they go about doing it - even to the point of hacking the development system for the core code.

If your not considering the latter, you could simply store the allowed ID as so, in a variable :

```
string AllowedID = "1234-ABCD-5678-EFGH";
```

Then, to check it against the users Windows OS Product ID you would probably need to query the registry (when i say product ID, i dont mean the serial code that is used to install the OS as storing this could have some ethical implications).

You could do something like this to retrieve the Product ID (tested on Win7 Ultimate x64):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string value64=null;
RegistryKey localKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
localKey = localKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion");
if (localKey != null)
{
value64 = localKey.GetValue("ProductID").ToString();
}
if (value64 == AllowedID)
{
MessageBox.Show("Successfully Authenticated");
//run the application functions etc
}
else
{
MessageBox.Show("Error Authenticting");
}
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are designing this application for windows OS's only, you want to look for something that is unique per system that is hard to change.

The MAC address can be spoofed, as can IPs and names. One thing that *can* be changed, but would be more trouble than it is worth, would be the Windows Product Key / Windows ID. On registering, take the product ID of the users OS and then make sure that the application checks this as being verified on launch.

Without an internet accessing application this becomes more of a problem as you would probably have to pre-code this into the application, compile and then sell the unique version onto the unique customer.

As mentioned, stopping hackers from reverse engineering your application is very difficult, especially if a salt or something isn't provided from an online source. As all the hackers will do is try and edit the source code to allow any key or something along those lines.

There are companies out there that will let you host small databases on their servers for a very small cost, so you could consider this rather than hosting a live server 24/7. For more information on this, feel free to send me an email / chat message.

I would recommend using some kind of internet / database query to make it harder for the hackers and then make sure this is fully encrypted, especially considering that the majority of people who own PC's now days have an internet connection.

If you take peoples OS Keys, another bonus is possibly being able to track the culprit back once it has been hacked.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thanks for this answer - I know I won't be able to beat everyone but the majority of the people who will be buying the product won't be programmers so I want a simple way of stopping them passing off the product elsewhere. Are resource/settings easily accessible without decoding an EXE file and can a full EXE be decoded? Last time I looked I couldn't find a tool that did it properly. Also do you have any code (C# pref) that could be used to help me store the computers ID in the registry/settings file on first use etc?

Comment: I added my reply as a new answer so i could fit the code in etc :)